# Unable to locate package koha-common

Tags: locate, package-info

I just have installed Koha on Ubuntu 16.4. But due to some reasons I have uninstalled it. Now I am trying to install it again but now it is telling E: unable to locate package. Please help.

Results of `sudo apt update`:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock- open (11: Resources temporarily unavailable). 
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, you error message says `Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/` and not `E: unable to locate package`.

If the error is: `Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/` that means that other package manager could be running in background, so please execute the following to check for that:

`ps aux | grep '[a]pt'`

If in the output of this command there's a process running using apt-get, then the best action to take is to wait for some time until it finishes. Otherwise you can kill it using:

`sudo pkill <nameOfTheProgram> -f` or `sudo killall -s KILL <nameOfTheProgram>`

After you're sure that there is no process using `apt`, you can remove the lock file using:

`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`

And then try to re-install koha-common with the command:

`sudo apt-get install koha-common`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad it worked! :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how you removed it but run the following commands from terminal to install it again:

```
echo deb http://debian.koha-community.org/koha stable main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/koha.list
wget -O- http://debian.koha-community.org/koha/gpg.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install koha-common
```

Source:

https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Koha_on_ubuntu_-_packages

Comment: Yes dear I have exactly followed these commands. But as I typed the last command and hit enter I am getting the error.

Comment: ok do `apt search koha-common` and what does it give you?

Comment: It says Full Text Search.....Done

Comment: Mine works I can see koha-common when I run a search!

Comment: Is there any other way? Or I will have to format the laptop.

Comment: No format needed, please run `sudo apt update` again then try to search for it...

Comment: Not working now something new is there. As I ran the sudo apt update command, following errors are coming:                       E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock- open (11: Resources temporarily unavailable).  E: Unable to lock directory   /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: Please post the errors into your question!

Comment: @KhushalChauhan That error means that some other package manager, probably updates, is running. Try again latter. That is the cause: If apt update doesn't run the list of available packages is not updated and because of that apt won't find the required package which resides on the PPA added by the first command.